# AspNet Core 1.1 Inject IOptions into a class

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using the Options pattern in my AspNet Core 1.1 application.  Everything is set according to the documentation:

```js
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
        
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
          ...
          services.Configure<AppOptions>(Configuration);
          ...
        }
```

I would like to inject the AppOptions class into a service that I am creating:

```js
public class MyService
{
private readonly AppOptions options;
  public MyService(IOptions<AppOptions> optionsAssesor)
        {
            options = optionsAssesor.Value;
        }
  
  ...
}
```

My questions is: when I try to create an instance of the MyService class like:

```js
MyService svc = new MyService();
```

I am getting an error saying that **There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter optionsAssesor** How can I take advantage of the DI and inject the AppOptions into my service?

I am kind of new to .NET Core so I am guessing I am missing something simple, but I cannot figure out what.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your json object you are attempting to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you are trying to get an instance of MyService from.  Basically you need to get a reference to the services collection (and register MyService in DI as well in startup), build a service provider, and then get the service.  This will allow DI to construct an instance of MyService and pass it in an instance of AppOptions.

For example:

```
var provider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

var myService = provider.GetService<MyService>();
```

That being said, in most places in ASP.NET Core you don't need to do this and are better off getting an instance of MyService through the Controller / Middleware constructor without having to build a Service Provider on your own.

You should look at the Microsoft Docs on Dependency Injection in ASP.NET core to further understand the different Service Lifetimes.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that Service (MyService) is within scope of ASP.net core project.

You have to do following Thing.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<MyService>();
    ... other things
}
```

Now Suppose that you are using your service ( or you want to use your service some controller then you have to do

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private MyService _myService = null;
    public HomeController(MyService service)
    {
         _myService = service;
    }
    // now you can use _myService in your controller method.
}
```

Every thing like you have to go through Dependency.

**Update 1**

Now suppose you want to use it in another class then you can do like this.

For example another class is MyClass1.

```
public class MyClass1 
{
     private MyService _myService = null;
     public MyClass1(MyService service)
     {
          _myService = service;
     }
}
```

Now if I am thinking correct then if you are using ASP.net core then MyClass1 one way or other it will use by Controller. You have to register dependency for this.

```
  services.AddScoped<MyClass1>(); // This should be in your ConfigureServices.
```

Comment: I am actually trying to use MyService in another class, not in a controller.  There I am getting the error when I try to create a new instance of MyService

Comment: In That Class to you can use same way as I have specified for controller. I am updating my example bit.